# Infield label not reappearing on empty field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code jquery plugin which was based on one from a while back (demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3rNpb/) that allows a label to fade in and out based on the user inputting to a field.

The label fades out 50% when a user focuses and then back in if they blur. When they begin typing the label hides completely. And then if the field is empty and they blur again then the label fades back in.

The issue is that when the field is focused and the user deletes the value it does not show the label at 50% again until they blur the field (unfocus).

Can anyone help fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there some specific part you want help with? Looking at your code, it just isn't coded to handle the scenario you describe. It unbinds the keydown event as soon as it hides the label, so you are not going to see the label again until the blur event gets called. I started making changes, but the changes required are more than I think is appropriate for a SO answer.

Comment: Yeah I mention it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your `keydown.infieldlabel` event handler, you have this call:

```
f.hideOnChange(e)
```

...and your `hideOnChange` function contains this code:

```
f.hideOnChange = function (e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 16) || (e.keyCode == 9)) return;
    if (f.showing) {
        f.$label.hide();
        f.showing = false
    };
    f.$field.unbind('keydown.infieldlabel')
};
```

It looks to me that the `unbind` call at the end of your function will cause the `keydown` event handling to stop; perhaps you have no event handling attached for your backspace or delete key anymore because the event is unbound.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You are going to have to modify your code to check for the proper values on keydown (keyup is actually better to use). The modifications needed are too extensive for a SO question (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, working fine

```
<label class="placeholder" for="test">Test Label</label>
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

```
(function ($) {
    $.InFieldLabels = function (b, c, d) {
        var f = this;
        f.$label = $(b);
        f.label = b;
        f.$field = $(c);
        f.field = c;
        f.$label.data("InFieldLabels", f);
        f.showing = true;
        f.init = function () {
            f.options = $.extend({}, $.InFieldLabels.defaultOptions, d);
            if (f.$field.val() != "") {
                f.$label.hide();
                f.showing = false
            };
            f.$field.focus(function () {
                f.fadeOnFocus()
            }).blur(function () {
                f.checkForEmpty(true)
            }).bind('keydown.infieldlabel', function (e) {
                f.hideOnChange(e)
            }).change(function (e) {
                f.checkForEmpty()
            }).bind('onPropertyChange', function () {
                f.checkForEmpty()
            })
        };
        f.fadeOnFocus = function () {
            if (f.showing) {
                f.setOpacity(f.options.fadeOpacity)
            }
        };
        f.setOpacity = function (a) {
            f.$label.stop().animate({
                opacity: a
            }, f.options.fadeDuration);
            f.showing = (a > 0.0)
        };
        f.checkForEmpty = function (a) {
            if (f.$field.val() == "") {
                f.prepForShow();
                f.setOpacity(a ? 1.0 : f.options.fadeOpacity)
            } else {
                f.setOpacity(0.0)
            }
        };
        f.prepForShow = function (e) {
            if (!f.showing) {
                f.$label.css({
                    opacity: 0.0
                }).show();
                f.$field.bind('keydown.infieldlabel', function (e) {
                    f.hideOnChange(e)
                })
            }
        };
        f.hideOnChange = function (e) {
            if ((e.keyCode == 16) || (e.keyCode == 9)) return;
            if (f.showing) {
                f.$label.hide();
                f.showing = false
            };
            f.$field.unbind('keydown.infieldlabel')
        };
        f.init()
    };
    $.InFieldLabels.defaultOptions = {
        fadeOpacity: 0.5,
        fadeDuration: 300
    };
    $.fn.inFieldLabels = function (c) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var a = $(this).attr('for');
            if (!a) return;
            var b = $("input#" + a + "[type='text']," + "input#" + a + "[type='password']," + "input#" + a + "[type='email']," + "input#" + a + "[type='tel']," + "textarea#" + a);
            if (b.length == 0) return;
            (new $.InFieldLabels(this, b[0], c))
        })
    }
})(jQuery);

$("label.placeholder").inFieldLabels();
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is listen for a `keyup` event and check to see if your `input` is empty upon each `keyup`. If it is, then you `fadeIn` your label.